# Project Euler #5 in Ruby with Prime class

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge

Question:

> Smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I tackle the problem with reference to how I solved #3, which is using the `prime_division` method in the `Prime` class. I have created an array of `prime_division`s for 2..20.

The array looks like this:

```
[[2, 1], [3, 1], [2, 2], [5, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1], [7, 1], [2, 3], [3, 2], [2, 1], [5, 1], [11, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [13, 1], [2, 1], [7, 1], [3, 1], [5, 1], [2, 4], [17, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [19, 1], [2, 2], [5, 1]]
```

And after using the `.uniq` method and sorting it, it shortens to the following:

```
[[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [5, 1], [7, 1], [11, 1], [13, 1], [17, 1], [19, 1]]
```

which is then easy, I just multiply the highest index for each factor:

\$2^4 \times 3^2  \times 5  \times 7  \times 11  \times 13  \times 17  \times 19 = 232792560\$

At this last stage, the right thing to do would be to multiply the highest power of each factor. I couldn't figure out how to do that in an elegant way.  However, I realised that coincidentally, the number of occurrences of each factor in array `b` always equals to the highest power. But I would welcome a more elegant solution to this.

```
require 'prime'

a=[]
c= 1


# Get all prime factors from 2 to 20
(2..20).each do |n|
    a = a.concat(Prime.prime_division(n))
end

# Select only the unique elements and extract the factor, multiply them all
b = a.uniq
b.each do |n|
    if n[0] != 0 || !n[0].nil?
        c = c * n[0]
    end
end 

puts c
```

Answer (score 2):

### Shortening

Building arrays by concatenating results to an empty list is inelegant.  You should strive to define the result "all at once":

```
a = (2..20).flat_map { |n| Prime.prime_division(n) }
```

Usually, one-blocks should be written using `{ … }`.  Use `do … end` if it spans multiple lines.

In the second half, `n[0]` should always be a prime number, so I don't see why it would ever be 0 or `nil`.  Therefore, you could finish up by writing

```
puts a.uniq.map { |prime, power| prime }.inject(:*)
```

### Refining

To find the maximum power of each prime, use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

```
require 'prime'

puts (2..20).flat_map { |n| Prime.prime_division(n) }
            .group_by { |prime, power| prime }.values
            .map { |factors| factors.max_by { |prime, power| power } }
            .map { |prime, power| prime ** power }
            .inject(:*)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers" is known as the Lowest Common Multiple. Does Ruby have such a method? Yes she does. Integers have a `lcm` method, which allows for:

```
p (1..20).inject(:lcm)
```